# how to upload file automatically in pertculer loacation using javascript(read /write) operation in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
 var tble = "<html><table><tr><td>212121</td></tr></table></html>";
```

i have to send this data to controller by storing it to some file on my hard Disk and load it form my Hard Disk and send to my controller.

Comment: Why do you need to store in local file and read again? If you want to send data you can simply check my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply pass the Html data to controller

Use `ValidateInput` attribute to skip the html/script validation in request

```
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Store(string html)
{

}
```

In jQuery Ajax

```
$.post('/Controller/Store/', {html:tble}, function(data){

});
```

Comment: one ques : var request = $.ajax({
               url: "../reports/Sendrt",//action method url which defined in controller
               type: 'POST',
               cache: false,
               data: JSON.stringify(tble),
               dataType: 'json',
               contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
           });

Comment: @user2408936, I am not getting you. You can format this code in your question itself, so other can understand